# Can i pass a class variable to it's other variables while initialising a class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a class named `BaseClass` like this

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context
```

I have some other classes which are derived from a base class like

```
BaseSubClass(object):
    def __init__(self, context=None):
        self.context = context

    def method1(self):
        """"Do stuff here """

    def method2(self):
        """"Do stuff here """

    def method3(self):
        """"Do stuff here """
```

then I have the classes Which are `sub classes of BaseSubClass`

```
class Class1(BaseSubClass):

    def get_something(self):
         """Perform some actions here on the basis of the context passed in self"""
        context = self.context
        return 'abcd'

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.get_something()

class Class2(BaseSubClass):

    def get_something(self):
         """Perform some actions here on the basis of the context passed in self"""
        context = self.context
        return 'abcdewewew'

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.get_something()



class Class3(BaseSubClass):

    def get_something(self):
         """Perform some actions here on the basis of the context passed in self"""
        context = self.context
        return 1221212

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.get_something()
```

and in the end what i have to do is

```
class MainClass(BaseClass):
    c1 = Class1()
    c2 = Class2()
    c3 = Class3()
```

what I want to do is. When i create the `BaseClass` object, Somehow i want to pass the `context` variable to it attribute classes also i.e `c1,c2,c3` so that when i access the attributes of that instance i will get the calculated data in first time. like

```
obj = MainClass(context)
obj.c1.data    # at this time it should return the actual data which will be depend on the context variable.
```

this is possible if i use the attributes as proerty . like

```
@property
def c1(self):
    return Class1(context=self.context).data

@property
def c2(self):
    return Class2(context=self.context).data
```

But i want to know that if i can pass the wrapper class variable to the classes which i am instantiating inside this wrapper class.

Comment: That does not work in this way. If you instantiate your base class you only have access to the methods available within the base class. You would have to instantiate the subclasses with your data. But on a side note. This whole construct looks horrible. I am almost certain that there is a better way to implement whatever you need...

Comment: Sounds like you might want to rethink your design.

Comment: Actually i have completed this task. Somewhere where i needed the context for the objects i have assigned context to the object `obj.context=self.context` and then called the method obj.method. I was just finding if there is any way.